# manage iOS app constant data: classes/objects or database

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm developing a iOS app in which I will have some objects (Animals, Real-Objects, Nature-Objects...). Each object have his own properties (in animal it may be sound, color...) and all the properties will be constant, I mean all my objects will be specified in my code and their values never change.

For example in my view1 i will have a Dog, a Cat, a Bike and a Tree. Every time i need a dog it will always have the same characteristics with the same values (sound: 'ruff', color: 'brown'...).

My actual approach is create classes (Animal, Real-Object, Nature-Object) and subclases of those classes for each object. So I will have a Dog class (which is a subclass of Animal), a Tree class (which is a subclass of Nature-Objects)... Each class has defined his own properties and constant values. When I need a Dog, I only have to create the object but all his values are specified in the definition of the class.

Is this the way to do it? Will be better save all the data to a file and read it when I need each object? Which is the best way to save and manage all this data?

I hope you understand my question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to create classes? Are you allowed to use dictionary?

Comment: Yes I can use dictionaries, but how can I use it for that?

Comment: Instead of creating classes for each object, create NSDictionary and since the 'characteristics' doesn't change then you could hardcode it. At least that would've been my approach.

Comment: and you think is better than create a database with all this data and just fetch the data when i need it? it's my first iOS app and i'm a little loose...

Comment: Depends on how many objects you want to create. I would probably create a plist file if I have more than 20 or more objects to make my life easier (since Apple made it easier to read plist file into NSDictionary). If I have less than 20, I would probably hardcode it.

Comment: This question is too high-level for SO, and should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is a technique, used in C++ and some other object-oriented languages, whereby an object can inherit data and behavior from multiple superclasses. For the sake of simplicity, Objective C does not include multiple inheritance directly. Most of the time, using protocols or categories instead is a better solution. However, thanks to dynamic typing, you can also provide much of the function of multiple inheritance using OpenStep's implementation of `NSObject`. Here's how:

[Reference by Apple doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA45894)

Comment: thanks, but i know how to implement the inheritance. My question is: as I have a lot of objects and all of them have always the same values in all their characteristics, the class-objects approach is better than create a database with all the objects, or maybe a dictionary?

Comment: sorry if i didn't express the question well..